# Python Warning in Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, new-operator

```
import random
userChoice = input('Pick "r", "p", "s": ')
computerChoice = random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])

p1 = str(userChoice)
p2 = str(computerChoice)

print("P1: Choose: ", p1)
print("P2: Choose: ", p2)


if p1 == p2 :
    print("DRAW!")
elif p1 is 'r' and p2 is 's' or p1 is 'p' and p2 is 'r' or p1 is 's' and p2 is 'p':
    print("Player 1: Has won the match")
else:
    print("Player 2: Has won the match")
```

My IDE spews warning when I am using this code?

Currently learning python, I would appreciate an explanation if possible!

Thank you.

The code works as is but I get errors before I run it saying logical error.

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: strings should not be compared with `is` (although it may work with short strings due to interning - but there is no guarantee this will always be the case)...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `is` use `==` as it is direct comparison.

```
elif p1 == 'r' and p2 == 's' or p1 == 'p' and p2 == 'r' or p1 == 's' and p2 == 'p':
    print("Player 1: Has won the match")
else:
    print("Player 2: Has won the match")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `==` instead of `is` to compare the characters:

```
elif p1 =='r' and p2 =='s' or p1 =='p' and p2 =='r' or p1 =='s' and p2 =='p':
```

since `==` compares if the value is the same, whereas `is` compares if they are pointing to the same object.

In your case, pyhton is tricky and tries to save memory for short string. but for longer strings comparing with `is` will not work